# Getting original $index of ng-repeat with toArray and groupBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 ng-repeats with a toArray and grouptBy in order to show the array grouped in Sections, with each repeating type as the Section header:

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | groupBy:'type' | toArray:true">
  <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
    <div>{{feed.$key}}</div>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-class="{'md-primary': !item.hide}"
          ng-click="toggleFeed($index)" ng-repeat="item in feed">
      {{item.name}}
    </md-button>
  </section>
```

I am trying to get the original `$index` so I can access `$scope.feeds` faster (using `$scope.feeds[$index]`).

Right now `$index` gives me the index within the second loop and `$parent.$index` gives me the index of the parents (first) loop, but I am trying to get the original index when clicking on the child.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't pass the index. Pass the item itself: `ng-click="toggleFeed(item)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the comments its much better to parse the selected object instead of the `$index`. In that way you don't need to struggle with your index/object/array changes (e.g. filter or sort).

### The good way:

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | groupBy:'type' | toArray:true">
    <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
        <div>{{feed.$key}}</div>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-class="{'md-primary': !item.hide}"
                   ng-click="toggleFeed(item)" ng-repeat="item in feed">
            {{item.name}}
        </md-button>
    </section>
</div>
```

---

### The worst way:

Keeping the original index is only possible with an unnecessary iteration. You need to prepare your data before parsing it into your view scope. I would no recommend to do this because it's not that performant. Keep it simple and parse your object into your `toggleFeed()` function.

```
$scope.data = [{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
},{
    someAttribute: 'value'
}];

$scope.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
    $scope.data[index].originalIndex = index;
});

$scope.feeds = $scope.data;
```

In that way you are able to parse to original index to your function:

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | groupBy:'type' | toArray:true">
    <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
        <div>{{feed.$key}}</div>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-class="{'md-primary': !item.hide}"
                   ng-click="toggleFeed(feed.originalIndex)" ng-repeat="item in feed">
            {{item.name}}
        </md-button>
    </section>
</div>
```

**The first approach is simple and much more performant.**

Comment: That is my current solution, but then I need to find the item in the array of objects...I was wondering if it is possible to pass it directly

Comment: It works like that....but my original question is: "I am trying to get the original $index so I can access $scope.feeds faster (using $scope.feeds[$index])"

Comment: @Galgomedia no m8, you can not access it faster or more performant due to the procedure you have to include. I'll update my answer an you will see why your approach is not that good...

Comment: @Galgomedia check my update. The force is with you now.

Comment: thanks! I will find the object after in the array, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help =)